# Finding a multiplying matrix from its resultant.

Tags: matrices

For a Matrix $A$ and a Matrix $B$ for which we have that $AB=R$ can we determine $B$ from $R$ and $A$ ?

Comment: If $A$ is square and full rank, then $B=A^{-1}R$.

Comment: What is A is not square?

Comment: If $A$ has a left inverse then the same manipulation works. Note that $A$ has a left inverse if and only if it represents an injective linear map, if and only if its null space is trivial, if and only if its columns are linearly independent, if and only if its rank equals the number of columns. (In particular, a necessary but not sufficient condition is that if $A$ is $m \times n$, then $m \geq n$.)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am working on a steganography program. I end up with a large number of characters (to mark letter distances) that I would like to manage as a matrix. I need to factor the matrix. That is the reason for my question.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is square and full rank, then $B=A^{-1}R$. When $A$ is tall, you may not be able to get a $B$ that satisfies the solution for any $R$ and $A$; this is an over-determined linear system. You can in general get a $B$ that will satisfy the relation $AB=R$ (if you know there must exist an answer) if you set $B = A^\dagger R$ where $A^\dagger$ is the pseudo-inverse of $A$. When $A$ is short, the problem is under-determined and you will get some solution that works, but maybe not the one you want.